# How to create a static placeholder in django-cms?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am following the tutorial here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html

I added the following to my `base.html`:

```
<footer>
    {% static_placeholder 'footer' %}
</footer>
```

I can not figure out how to edit the content of the static placeholder. Is that done in the django-cms interface, or on the filesystem?

- I created a `footer.html` file my `templates` directory, but the content is not being rendered in my page.
- I switched to Draft mode, then Content, but double-click my page does not bring up the editor. This may be a different issue.

Comment: After you've added the static placeholder.. have you resaved the page?

Comment: yes, I had tried that. But it's a good suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I wanted to get a "bare bones" site running as quickly as possible, so I did not install all of the suggested django-cms plugins. Now that I have the plugins installed, it's working!